# Error 404 Not found for @font-face files

Tags: css, font-face, laravel-5

I am loading css using the following in `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/materialize.css') }}" media="screen" />
```

The page is not able to find the fonts used in the css file in the fonts directory mentioned under public folder. How am i supposed to load these for the css files ?

Image of Folder Struxture & Calling of font-face in the css file:

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Sorry I can't read your screen shot, but have you tried CSS URLs starting from `"/folders/to/the/fonts"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you wrote "font", but it is "fonts" in directory structure.

Comment: well spotted, typo :)